# "string or binary data would be truncated" when deleting row

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express to connect to our SQL Server 2005 (think its 2005, its version 9.000 something something). I have a table with one column that saves a lot of text. I have set the column type to text. When i have a row with lots of text in this column i cannot delete it. I get the message "string or binary data would be truncated" when i try to delete it. If i try to edit the row i get the same message. What do i do?

**Considerable** : i fix it by drop table and create it again, but i wanna a Solution!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally this kind of error happens when you're inserting a long value into the column that can't store it. Check whether you don't have any triggers or any related logic that could do that on your behalf when you're deleting the row (e.g. for logging purposes / audit trail)

Comment: my column type is ntext and this happened when i want to delete row...see last sentence, Updated

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I can neither change the value nor delete the row, also with an `ntext` field.

Comment: I have same problem, and no there are no triggers.

Comment: The answer below by @hbb-zr correctly answer this question (it's a glitch in Management Studio). 

OP: Please consider changing the accepted answer.

Answer (score 28):

Though I'm late to the party, when I review the original poster's description of the problem, it sounds like they are trying to delete the row from within the table editor interface.  I just encountered this same issue with a table containing a "text" column with long text, and it appears that the issue may in fact be tied to a limitation in the editor itself.  From my own investigation, it appears that you will not be able to edit a row in which a text column exceeds 4000 characters.  I tested with SSMS 2008 R2.

Hopefully this will help anyone else encountering this error.

Comment: In this case I've deleted that record by means of SQL query and next I've added new one with corrected long text data.

Comment: Thanks for posting this, Ted.  I had the error when attempting to change a bit field to 0 in the editor interface, so I was pretty mystified.  This proved to be the problem for me as well.

Answer (score 15):

I had same problem and solved ...
after selecting top 200 row of your table, click the "Show Criteria Pane"(left side of toolbar)
now uncheck your ntext column (the column holding a big text you was talking about)
now you can delete or update any row :)

Comment: Visual Studio 2013: Press `Ctrl+2`, or right-click inside Results Pane, then select Pane > Criteria to display the Criteria Pane. Now clear the Output flag for the column(s), and you should be able to delete the row.

Answer (score 1):

I changed my data type to nvarchar(MAX) and was able to edit and delete as I saw fit.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered there was a trigger that audited changes to the record (thanks Tomas Vana), but the target audit record had a limited varchar field for the action report (varchar(1000)). It was trying to audit the deletion of records that had varchar(max) fields...duh!

I changed the action report field in the log to varchar(max) and that fixed it...
bloody obvious really...:)

Comment: Wow good point, I got a trigger that audit every change for that table, I wrote it myself and forgot about it, it was my issue there